# post request of HttpClient of angular is not sending the proper data to server

Tags: json, angular, typescript, spring-boot, rest

In my below code, request is holding data `{widgetName: "widgetName", widgetCriteria: "Activities", followUpDate: "1591727400000", uid: "someId"}`

```
let request = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.assign(this.registrationForm.value, ...req)));
      delete request.widgetFIlterOptions;
      let uid = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user")).uid;
      request.uid = uid; 
      this.openWindow = false;
      console.info("request-->", request);
      this.contactService.addWidget(request).subscribe(res=> {
        this.emService.updateWidgits();
      })
```

Inside addWidget() function/method we are calling post request.
but after calling post request ResetController class should receive "followUpDate" with the other data. However in my case "followUpDate" is missing but I can see other data.

Can anyone help in this matter? What I am missing here? I am new to Angular.

```
addWidget(widget, data?) {

    console.info("widget-->", widget); // here followUpDate is present
    this.http.post(this.api.createWidget, widget).pipe(map(data => {
        console.info("data-->", data); // this does not have the followUpDate.
        let message = "Widget created successfully";
        data['data'] = this.filterWidgets(data).length > 0 ? this.filterWidgets(data): alert("No data Available");
        this.widgets.unshift(data);
        this.toastr.success(message);
    }),catchError(err => {
      this.toastr.error(err.error);
      return throwError(err);
    }));
```

Below is my rest controller class

```
@RestController
public class DashboardController {

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @PostMapping(path = "createcriteria", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "create the deal", response = Dashboard1.class)
    public Dashboard1 saveCriteria(@RequestBody Dashboard1 dashboard1) {

         System.out.println(dashboard1); // here "followUpDate" is missing
         return service.saveCriteria(dashboard1);
    }
}
```

Below is my Dashboard1 class

```
@Document(collection = "Dashboard1")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Dashboard1 {

    @Id
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The database generated product ID")
    private String  id;

    @Field(value = "widgetname")
    private String WidgetName = null;
    @Field(value = "widgetcriteria")
    private String WidgetCriteria = null;
    @Field(value = "uid")
    private String uid = null;
    @Field(value = "activitytype")
    private String activityType = null;
    @Field(value = "contactname")
    private String contactName = null;
    @Field(value = "updateby")
    private String updateBy = null;
    @Field(value = "followUpDate")
    private String followUpDate = null;

    // below all the getters, setters and toString() methods present
}
```

Comment: Well we can at least debug where the issue occurs, I'd expect it to be something related to deserialization. What happens if you send the exact same json as you posted in the question via Postman to the Java backend? Does it have the `followUpDate` in there?

Comment: @IvarReukers Sorry for late reply... tried today from postman but still not getting "followUpDate" in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to JSON.stringfy the object. You just need to certify that the attribute names on json are the same of your class on spring, and just sed the pure object without the stringfy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my code. Issue was in getters and setters. In my code field name and getter and setter name was different. Field name was `followUpDate`  but the getter and setter name was `getFallowUpDate()` and `setFallowUpDate(String)`